# Query for unfulfilled IAP when using Windows.Services.Store

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

We've migrated our app from using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` to `Windows.Services.Store` as suggested int he documentation. However, we can't seem to find any way to query for and fulfill unfulfilled purchases. With the old API, we could call `GetUnfulfilledConsumablesAsync` to get the unfulfilled products, loop through those and fulfill them when the app started. There doesn't seem to be anything equivalent to this with the new API. We also get an empty array of items when querying the REST API (https://collections.mp.microsoft.com/v6.0/collections/query), so I assume that is only returning fulfilled items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I can tell, the new `getUserCollectionAsync` method only returns consumables that haven't yet been "fulfilled," so it effectively does the same thing.
2. The REST API wasn't returning anything because the Azure Active Directory client ID hadn't been added to the app in the Partner Dashboard. Around 24 hours after this it started returning the results correctly.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You could use `storeContext.GetUserCollectionAsync` method to get the add-ons of the current app for which the user has purchased. And then work with the `StoreContext.GetConsumableBalanceRemainingAsync` method to get the remaining balance for the unfulfilled consumable add-on for the current app.